# Android lint error with ?: conditional operator operator

Tags: android, conditional-statements

```
int color = (colorString != null) ?
                someIntReturningMethod(colorString) :
                ContextCompat.getColor(c, R.color.defaultForWhatever);
notificationBuilder.setColor(color);
```

I get "Should pass resolved color instead of resource id here".

If I remove the ?: and leave color defined as either one, Lint has no problems.

Can I fix this without suppressing any useful warnings? If not, which one do I suppress?

Please no ad-hoc solutions for this problem specifically. I'm asking about ?: confusing lint.

**[edit]** So, no solution for "?: confusing Lint", in general?

Comment: use supress warning only for that statement

Comment: also you can annotate @colorres to your method

Comment: Put your cursor on the warning. Press Alt + Enter will show different options, including solutions and suppress warnings.

Comment: Yeah, //noinspection ResourceAsColor before the line helped, thanks.

Comment: an annotation it is to tell lint that method return a color Res

Comment: Sorry, comment edition. I was asking about @ColorRes, letter case was wrong.

Comment: yeah that is what i explained what it is , also please accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@ColorInt` annotation to annotate that method so lint wont throw a warning

Answer (score 0):

Modify Your code as follows:

```
int color;
if (colorString != null) {
     color = someIntReturningMethod(colorString);
} else {
    color = R.color.defaultForWhatever;
}
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(c, color);
```

`someIntReturningMethod` is not returning a resolved Android color. Probably it just returns a color from `res/colors.xml`, which must be later resolved with method:
`ContextCompat.getColor(Context context, int color)`

Comment: Both a "resolved color" and a "resource ID" are ints. ANd yes, it's an ARGB.